# catkin_ws reset

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, catkin-ws

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello, I am kind of new to the whole ROS environment and I would appreciate if anyone could help me out with what seems of a simple task.

I have been playing around making many different packages and downloading them as well wanting to learn how everything worked. I have done also several workspaces other than catkin_ws. Anyways, I kind of understand how to do things in an ordered way now but it is such a disorder that I want to erase all and start over with a simple catkin_ws with the core packages.

I'm looking for someone that can tell me the steps on how to erase all the junk and make a single catkin_ws with just the core packages.

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/324890/catkin_ws-reset/) by [abeckd](https://answers.ros.org/users/42114/abeckd/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2019-06-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Removing a Catkin workspace completely is simple: just `rm -rf` the workspace directory (not the `src`, `devel` or `build` space, but the root of the workspace).

There's nothing more to.

If you've added a `source /path/to/your/catkin_ws/devel/setup.bash` to your `$HOME/.bashrc`, you'll want to remove that for the workspaces you've deleted as well, otherwise you'll get errors whenever you open a new shell.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2019-06-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-06**:
Probably redundant, but: if you `rm -rf` a workspace, you *cannot undo* that. You're physically removing the files from your disk.

**Comment by [abeckd](https://answers.ros.org/users/42114/abeckd/) on 2019-06-06**:
Thank you for the answer, I was afraid I wouldn't be able to get my default packages for turtlebot3 back but I found both git clones I needed. Basically I just `rm -rf` all workspaces, then created a new `~/catkin_ws/src` cloned both git in and then `catkin_make`

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2019-06-06**:
Do you actually need to build the TB3 packages in a Catkin workspace?

According to [wiki/turtlebot3](http://wiki.ros.org/turtlebot3) they've been released into both Kinetic and Melodic and should be installable with a simple `sudo apt install ros-kinetic-turtlebot3`.